# how to avoid duplication in BigQuery by streaming insert

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery

I made a function that inserts .CSV data into BigQuery in every 5~6 seconds. I've been looking for the way to avoid duplicating the data in BigQuery after inserting. I want to remove data that has same luid but I have no idea how to remove it so is it possible to check each data of .CSV has already existed in BigQuery table before inserting .
I put row_ids parameter to avoid duplicate luid but it seems not to work well .
Could you give me any idea ?? Thanks.

```
def stream_upload():
    # BigQuery
    client = bigquery.Client()
    project_id = 'test'
    dataset_name = 'test'
    table_name = "test"
    full_table_name = dataset_name + '.' + table_name
    json_rows = [] 
    with open('./test.csv','r') as f:
        for line in csv.DictReader(f):
            del line[None]
            line_json = dict(line)
            json_rows.append(line_json)

    errors = client.insert_rows_json(
        full_table_name,json_rows,row_ids=[row['luid'] for row in json_rows]
    )

    if errors == []:
        print("New rows have been added.")
    else:
        print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))

    print("end")

schedule.every(0.5).seconds.do(stream_upload)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't have a native way to deal with this. You could either create a view off of this table that performs deduping or create an external cache of `luids` and lookup if they have already been written to BigQuery before writing and update the cache after writing new data. This could be as simple as a file cache or you could use an additional database.

Comment: Thank you for your idea . I will try that way .